# RVM in "Relocated Items" folder as part of Catalina Upgrade

Tags: ruby, rvm, macos-catalina

After installing Catalina on my mac, my .rvm folder (labelled User_Profile.rvm) was moved into the "Relocated Items" as described [here][1].

I initially just tried to reinstall RVM by using

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

But this returns an error:

```
mkdir: /User_Profile.rvm/src: Read-only file system
```

It seems that the RVM install wants to write directly to the newly protected folder structure on Catalina... Has anyone else run into this or found a fix? I'm wondering if there is an option to specify where RVM should be installed to.

Comment: Just reinstall it.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall - Updated my description above to reflect.

Comment: Post the **exact** log showing all the steps leading up to and after that error message. It looks like you're substituting the string `User_Profile` instead of showing the actual and exact error message you're showing.

Comment: Post the complete log, not just the error message. Also, is your user profile stored at `/User_Profile`? Not in `/Users/User_Profile`? Because if so that's probably your issue.

Comment: I don't know how to access or post the log...